# Get string after last double slashes in JSR223

Tags: java, jmeter, jsr223

I have a `JSR223 Sampler` in `JMeter` to get string after last //. `currentFile` named string contains name of a JMeter variable, which contains a filepath.

```
String filen = vars.get(${currentFile});
filen=filen.replaceFirst(".*//(\\w+)","$1");
```

I get error message:

> Response message: javax.script.ScriptException:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed: Script80.groovy: 8: unexpected char: '\' @ line 8,
>   column 36.
>          filen=filen.replaceFirst(".*//(\w+)","$1");
>                                         ^

Comment: Why not just split the string on '/' and take the last element?

Comment: @SBylemans : Sorry, I edited question with some additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use Groovy for this. It has a nice operator for it:

```
String filen = vars.get("currentFile");
def result = filen =~ /.*\/\/(.*)/; //matches end of the string after the last //
if (result.hasGroup()) {
    filen = result[0][1]
    log.info("file:"+filen)
}
```

Comment: I have double slashes. Which one should be duplicated?

Comment: it matches //. You see the \/\/.. Because of the regex is separated by / you have to escape the / with \. Therefor the \/ to match a /.

Comment: I get error in this case: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index is out of range 0..-1 (index = 0)`

Comment: Tell me the value of the currentFile so I can reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

As per [JSR223 Sampler Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

> JMeter processes function and variable references before passing the script field to the interpreter, so the references will only be resolved once. Variable and function references in script files will be passed verbatim to the interpreter, which is likely to cause a syntax error. In order to use runtime variables, please use the appropriate props methods, e.g.
>
> ```
> props.get("START.HMS");
> props.put("PROP1","1234");
> ```

So you need to replace this line:

```
String filen = vars.get(${currentFile});
```

with this one:

```
String filen = vars.get('currentFile');
```

Check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't enough specific: currentFile named String contains the exact name of JMeter variable, which value I should get.

Comment: You will need to show `currentFile` variable value and indicate what do you want to get from it

Comment: So, an example. currentFile's value is `path_1` and path_1 value is `C:\_private\myfile.pdf`

Comment: Then you should do `String filen = vars.get(vars.get("currentFile"))` and your regex might be wrong too, I think `.*(\\/|\\\\)(\\w+)` will work..

Comment: Instead of going for regular expresion I woudl recommend going for [FileNameUtils.getName()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getName(java.lang.String)) function like  `def filen = org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.getName(vars.get(vars.get('currentFile')))`

Comment: I am unable to create new file from string :javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method java.io.File#<init>.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:

Comment: It indicates the fact that you don't have the var with the value of `currentFile`